# Getting JavaScript-errors when authenticating using ADAL

Tags: c#, office365, adal, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the [Microsoft Graph API](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/) and am successfully querying a user's meetings and emails. A user (testing the application) reported a JavaScript-error during the authentication process with Office 365 (using [ADAL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/)), see Screenshot below.

A few months ago I noticed these pop-ups too, but they were gone after I've updated the ADAL **Nuget**-Package. I just checked and there is no update available (current version: 4.0.209160138-alpha).

I myself **cannot reproduce the issue**. It might be that using different O365 tenants cause this issue in some cases (as they load different login-screens), or something else.

Did somebody experience similar errors, knows why/when this happens and a fix for it?

[image: Javascript error when authenticating with O365 using ADAL]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether user able to open this url or not URL:- https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.4108.2/content/cdnbundles/jquery.1.11.min.js

If not then there the above mentioned url is block and hence user will get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

IE can get into a state where it's throws up dialog boxes for every little JS error. [Here are instructions to disable it](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/what-do-internet-explorer-script-errors#1TC=windows-7) - Internet Options -> Advanced -> Check "Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)" and uncheck "Display a notification about every script error"