# Getting JavaScript-errors when authenticating Winform App using ADAL

Tags: c#, winforms, azure-active-directory, adal

Am using winforms and I am using Microsoft Graph API (ADAL) to authenticate our users. Everthing was working good. Starting from yesterday I start getting this JS error and when you click Yes or No its still working fine, Can any one know why this start showing?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341121/getting-javascript-errors-when-authenticating-using-adal) SO question?

Comment: Permanently enable the IE11 compatibility mode and extended features: [How can I get the WebBrowser control to show modern contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38514184/how-can-i-get-the-webbrowser-control-to-show-modern-contents?answertab=active#tab-top) -- [Web browser control emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626667/7444103).

Answer (score 0):

Is the authentification in a `WebBrowser`?
If yes you can block them by setting `ScriptErrorsSuppressed` to true.
I don't know if it blocks any importent javascript scripts.

Solution from here: [Disable JavaScript error in WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476360/disable-javascript-error-in-webbrowser-control)

Comment: Not its not in a webBrowser. Am using "Microsoft.Identity.Client" to open Microsoft authentication form